# Codenames, Tags, and Build Numbers

Tags: android

I am not able to understand this code name convection if somebody know it please make me understandable and tell me what does it really want to convey form its code name in Android

The letter counts quarters, with A being Q1 2009. Therefore, F is Q2 2010. The two digits count days within the quarter, so F85 is June 24 2010.

https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html

Comment: A = Q1 2009, B = Q2 2009,  C = Q3 2009,  D = Q4 2009,  E = Q1 2010 , F = Q2 2010. F85 => 85 = 30 (days of April) + (31 days of May) + 24June

Answer (score 0):

if you call `A = Q1 2009`, the you will have that  `B = Q2 2009`, `C = Q3 2009,` `D = Q4 2009`, `E = Q1 2010` , `F = Q2 2010`. The 85th days in the second Quartal is June the 24th, because 85 is the sum of `30`, the days of April, `31` the days of May, plue the 24th day of June.

```
F85 => 85 = 30 (days of April) + (31 days of May) + 24June
```